# How to get credit memo created date magento?

Tags: magento

How to get credit memo created date time in magento transnational email ?

```
{{var creditmemo.getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime('short')}}
```

Comment: which transactional email you are looking for?

Comment: order transnational email template

Comment: Are you talking about email which send when order is placed?

Comment: after order i have create credit memo that order, then customer got a credit memo email, how to set credit memo created time on that email template.

Answer (score 1):

You can get creditmemo created date and time using this code.

```
{{var creditmemo.created_at}}
```

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it so it will help other community as well.

Comment: it works for me but need to change formate 2020-04-24 17:18:34==>April 24, 2020 at 9:07:42 a.m. MDT